# Desktop Sharing in Python

Tags: python, remote-desktop

I want to develop a desktop sharing Program(like Teamviewer but over Browser) with other additional functionalities, like file sharing, chat, video conference. My question is, is something like this doable using only Python? 
I am thinking of using PyJamas for UI, and Socket and OS for network connection.
Any tips if this would work or would be waste of time?

Thanks.

Comment: underresearched. Have you figured out a way to run Python in your browser? If yes, notify the browser makers, please.

Comment: Sorry, I have not. I am new to Python. So was hoping that someone points me in right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not run python in a browser (you can run it in a virtual shell but it does not interact with the browser). I would recommend using a software already built or if you really want to build one you will have to use a different programming language. It would be VERY complicated. Feel free if you want too. I would love to see the finished product.

One that has all the features you want that I LOVE is called ScreenConnect from ConnectWise. The free version has most of those features but if you want all it is only $200 a year. You can customize everything like you are editing the html page. It is amazing. Check it out.

https://www.screenconnect.com/

Sorry and good luck. 
Welcome to the wonderful world of programming!

Comment: Thanks Brendan. Which programming language do you think would be best for it?

Comment: I would think maybe HTML + JS?

Comment: @MUSR did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!